# mysql : When representing mandatory and disjoint relationships in mysql, can two records from the two child tables have same value as primary keys?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

I found this diagram in my lecture notes.

[image]

In the logical model, staffNo is taken as primary key in both the child entities. Now, is it allowed for a record in PermStaff and a record in ConsultStaff to have the same value in it's staffNo {PK} field?

For example if I set staffNo to auto-increment, many records in both tables will have same primary key.

Comment: In the second model, there isn't a **Staff** table, and there isn't a relationship between the two tables. Since there isn't a relationship between the tables, there isn't **collision** with the primary keys. Just because a column in two tables contains the same value doesn't mean there's a problem.

Comment: Whether it is allowed to have the same pk in both tables depends on your business requirements. Technically, these two tables are independent of each other, so on database level there is no requirement to have different keys. In reality, though, you would want staff ids to be unique, so they clearly identify a person.